# How to rename key of object with a variable?

Tags: javascript, json

I have got an object:

```
blocks: [
  {
    type: 'animal',
    data: { text: 'Bark bark' }
  },
  {
    type: 'human',
    data: { text: 'Speak speak' }
  },
  ...
]
```

The `data:` naming does not fit my needs and I would like to rename it with the `type` value. So It should look like this:

```
blocks: [
  {
    type: 'animal',
    animal: { text: 'Bark bark' }
  },
  {
    type: 'human',
    human: { text: 'Speak speak' }
  },
  ...
]
```

How can I achieve this with very little code of javascript? My solution does work but seems to be stupid (especially if you consider 10+ different kind of types):

```
const blocks = [];
oldBlocks.map(block => {
    const {type, data} = block;
    blocks.push({
        type: type,
        animal: type === "animal" ? data : undefined,
        human: type === "human" ? data : undefined,
        ....
    });
});
```

Comment: @sideshowbarker you are right, this is somehow a duplicate and I found the linked thread, but I was not able to understand it. Luckily zfrisch nailed it down to the most simple example :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use brackets to denote an expression inside of an object, allowing you to evaluate variables as key names:

```
blocks.map(({type, data}) => ({ type, [type]: data }));
```

---

### Example:

```js
let blocks = [
  {
    type: 'animal',
    data: { text: 'Bark bark' }
  },
  {
    type: 'human',
    data: { text: 'Speak speak' }
  }
],


result = blocks.map(({type, data}) => ({ type, [type]: data }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @zfrisch, that's as simple as it could be. Thanks for letting me know :-)

Answer (score 1):

A possible Solution:

```
for i in blocks:
i["'"+i[type]+"'"]=i['data']
delete(i['data'])
```